# Fineuploader open queued items

Tags: fine-uploader

Is it possible to open files directly from the list of the stored items. I want to implement this function so that the user can check the files before they getting uploaded.

Comment: What do you mean by "open files"? Do you want to display a preview of the file in browser (if possible) to quickly show the user, or do you want the user to open the file in another application to verify the file manually before uploading? Or am I misunderstanding? Could you not use Fine Uploader's validation options to perform some checks on the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to allow users to open submitted files in an external application via the browsers by clicking on these files (for example), this is not really possible.  The browser does not provide sufficient access to the file system to make this possible.  As Mark mentioned, Fine Uploader will already optionally [generate previews for images](http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/thumbnails.html).  We intend to look into [providing client-side previews for audio and video files](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1000) in the future as well.